# after delete endl in cout << "hello" << endl, my C++ program stopped working

Tags: c++

This is my code. This code can run well. 
But when I delete "endl" in "cout << "Hello world!" << endl;", It can't run.[This is what I get when delete endl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eEHE.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char * name;
    char * n = "aaaa";
    strcpy(name, n);
    cout << name;
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The following is the code that deleted endl.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char * name;
    char * n = "aaaa";
    strcpy(name, n);
    cout << name;
    cout << "Hello world!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, copy/paste error message inside your post instead of giving a link to a picture

Comment: Maybe read a [`strcpy` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets take a look at these lines:

```
char * name;
char * n = "aaaa";
strcpy(name, n);
```

The variable `name` is not initialized. It's contents is *indeterminate* and will be seemingly random. Using it as a destination for a `strcpy` call will lead to *undefined behavior*.

If you want to use C-style strings, you need to allocate memory for `name`, for example by using an array:

```
char name[128];
```

---

But if you are actually programming in C++, why don't you use the awesome classes that comes with the standard library? For example the [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class that are very good at handling strings:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string name;
    std::string n = "aaaa";

    name = n;

    std::cout << name << '\n';
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`name` is an uninitialized pointer : it points at some random memory location. When you `strcpy` to it, you trample five bytes at that location, replacing them with `aaaa\0`.

Formally, this is undefined behaviour. In practice, you have witnessed two different symptoms : no apparent effect, and a crash.

Point `name` at a sufficiently large buffer that you actually own, and all will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

`char * name;`
This line 'name' is not initialised and holds garbage.

Instead do something like:

```
 using namespace std;
 int main(){

   char name[10];
   char  *n = "aaaa";
   strcpy(name, n);
   cout << name;
   cout << "Hello world!";

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're copying into a garbage address.

```
char * name; //<<<garbage address
char * n = "aaaa";
strcpy(name, n);
```